# How to seperate columns into rows in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

For example, I have three relationship in the database

```
(0001)-[relation1]-(node3)

(0001)-[relation2]-(node3)

(0002)-[relation3]-(node3)
```

I want to query those relationship between 0001, 0002 and their common friends

```
MATCH(s1:Person{name:'0001'})-[f1]->(x),(s2:Person{name:'0002'})-[f2]-(x) return f1, f2
```

However, it return 2 rows with 2 columns

```
f1                            f2                            
relation1                     relation3
relation2                     relation3
```

How to make the result in 3 rows with single column?

```
relation1
relation2
relation3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can COLLECT() and then add the collections together, then UNWIND:

```
MATCH(s1:Person{name:'0001'})-[f1]->(x),(s2:Person{name:'0002'})-[f2]-(x) 
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT f1) + COLLECT(DISTINCT f2) as rels
UNWIND rels as rel
RETURN rel
```